# I cant find the error. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ensure')

Tags: json, error-handling, discord, discord.js

Here is the code

```
    })
    client.Jobmute = new CronJob('*/5 * * * * *', async function() {
        client.mutes.ensure("MUTES", {
            MUTES: []
        })
        let data = client.mutes.get("MUTES")
        var unmutes = data.MUTES.filter(v=>{
            return v.mutetime > 0 && v.mutetime - (Date.now() - v.timestamp) <= 0
        })
```

I have tried everything I've seen online.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if client.mutes is defined and is an object using the typeof operator.

```
client.Jobmute = new CronJob('*/5 * * * * *', async function() {
    // Make sure client.mutes is defined and is an object
    if (!client.mutes || typeof client.mutes !== 'object') {
        client.mutes = new Map(); // Initialize client.mutes as a Map or the appropriate data structure
    }

    client.mutes.ensure("MUTES", {
        MUTES: []
    });

    let data = client.mutes.get("MUTES");
    var unmutes = data.MUTES.filter(v => {
        return v.mutetime > 0 && v.mutetime - (Date.now() - v.timestamp) <= 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, after doing that the error changed to TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') at CronJob.<anonymous> any reasons why?